# Solution to integral equation involving logarithms

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, integral-equations

In the [Handbook of Integral Equations](http://dl.iranidata.com/book/daneshgahi/Handbook%20of%20Integral%20Equations%202008.pdf) (1.4-1, 1.4-2), solutions are given for $y$ in the equations

$$\int_0^x{\ln(x-t)y(t)}\ dt = f(x)$$

and

$$\int_0^x{(\ln x-\ln t)y(t)}\ dt = f(x)$$

I’m interested in solving

$$\int_0^x{(\ln(x-t)-\ln x)y(t)}\ dt = f(x)$$

I tried using variable substitutions or a combination of the above two problems, but couldn’t make anything work.

Answer (score 1):

The equation is equivalent to
\begin{equation}
\int_0^x\ln\left( 1-\frac{t}{x} \right)y(t)\,dt=f(x)
\end{equation} 
or
\begin{equation}
\int_0^1\ln\left( 1-u \right)y(ux)\,du=\frac{f(x)}{x}
\end{equation} 
A solution can be found if $f(x)$ can be represented as a series
\begin{equation}
f(x)=x^\lambda\sum_{n=0}^N f_nx^n
\end{equation} 
we can express
\begin{equation}
y(x)=x^\lambda\sum_{n=0}^N b_nx^n
\end{equation} 
By identifying the coefficients, we have
\begin{equation}
y(x)=x^\lambda\sum_{n=0}^N\frac{a_n}{I_n}x^{n-1}
\end{equation} 
where
\begin{equation}
I_n=\int_0^1 \ln(1-u)u^{n+\lambda-1}\,du
\end{equation} 
we have (G\&R 4.293.8)
\begin{align}
I_n&=-\frac{1}{n+\lambda}\left[\psi(n+\lambda+1)-\psi(1)\right]\\
\end{align} 
where $\psi$ is the digamma function. If $\lambda=0$, we have $I_0=-\pi^2/6$.